# Center align a multiple-row list

Tags: css

I would like to centrally align a multiple-row list within a div:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Wu2S/

In this example I have set a fixed width on the `ul` to demonstrate what I want to achieve. However, I need the width of the `ul` to be dynamic, so that it just contains the list items (which are fixed width), i.e. shrink to fit. Each row of list items should start from the left and fit as many items as it can before flowing onto a new line.

The `div` is variable width, so for example, if the `div` was a little wider it would look like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Wu2S/1/

I've tried all sorts, but it seems to be a lot more difficult than I had thought!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find essentially the same problem:

[CSS - how to make DIV with wrapped floats inside only be as large as it needs to be to hold the floats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983182/css-how-to-make-div-with-wrapped-floats-inside-only-be-as-large-as-it-needs-to/8987026)

It turns out there is no nice solution. One way is using media queries to set the width of the `ul`. The other way is using a jQuery plugin like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

I was probably going to use Masonry on my site anyway, so I think I'll go down this route, with non-javascript users falling back to a non-centered layout.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul {
    background-color: red;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I used 49% but you could use CSS `box-sizing: border-box` to avoid that and use a solid 50%.

Comment: I should also have specified that the list should fit as many list items per row as possible before flowing onto the next line e.g http://jsfiddle.net/8Wu2S/1/ I've just edited the question to make things a bit clearer.

Comment: Are your li's always a multiple of 100px? Or is this for demonstration purposes only? Does the UL have to have a background? Are all the lis the same width?

Comment: Just change the li width from 49% to 100px or whatever. The UL will still always be 80% or whatever max width you want of the parent div. Without a background you can't tell.

Comment: All `li`s are always 100px and the `ul` doesn't have to have a background. The `ul` can fill up to 100% of the `div`, but if I set the width to 100% (or auto) the ul is no longer centered: http://jsfiddle.net/8Wu2S/2/

Answer (score 0):

Set the ul and li elements to display inline.

```
 <div style="width:20%;">
     <ul style="display:inline;">
       <li style="display:inline;">Foo</li>
       <li style="display:inline;">bar</li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/QcNTW/4/

Comment: Pretty sure he wants the ul to only be the width of the lis. Your example is 100% width if the parent.

Comment: Yes, as Leeish said, the `ul` should only be the width of the `li`s contained within. It's proving quite difficult to explain what I'm trying to achieve!

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. I updated the example to set both the ul and li elements to render as inline, but I don't think this gives you exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this easily with flexbox.  http://jsfiddle.net/51kdt4pc/6/

Here are the key changes:

```
ul {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```